# Creating a table in SQL with column that will not accept abbreviations

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, create-table

I’m tasked with creating a table in SQL for addresses. However, the country column may not accept any abbreviations; just full names.

How do I do this? Would it be through a Case just right after countries varchar?

Tried using

```
CREATE TABLES addresses (
…
country varchar (25),
CASE
WHEN ‘UK’ THEN ‘United Kingdom’
WHEN ‘US’ THEN ‘United States’
…
ELSE 0
END
NOT NULL,
);
```

Comment: How do you know whether a text is an abbreviation or not? The countries with the shortest names have four letters, so you could use a check constraint that the countries must have a length of least 4. If none of the abbreviations have 4 letters or more, this should do.

Comment: I would create a table that maps common abbreviations to full names. Then add an `ON INSERT or UPDATE` trigger that looks at `NEW.country` value and does a lookup. If it is an abbreviation then change `NEW.country` to the full name.

Comment: Rather than just common abbreviations create a table that implements [ISO 3166](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) (i.e 3166-1 alpha-2, 3166-1 alpha-3 and 3166-1 numeric). For completeness you can then add the full name as a *code* and/or any local abbreviations. Then as @AdrianKlaver suggests fire a trigger that looks up the value.  NOTE: Be careful of length specification, some names are lengthier than you have allowed.